# Java double LinkedList remove node

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

So the idea is to make a Double Ended Priority Queue so far I have got a tree like structure using 2 Linked Lists, I have and interface I have to stick with with no alterations to it. The problem I have got is I have to make 2 methods called getMost and getLeast which gets the most or least node and then makes that node null. But these 2 methods are  proving quite difficult to make. How would you go about doing it?

I have tried using recursion but this is proving difficult as I have to select the tree by going tree.root but passing in tree.root into a recursive method always starts it from tree.root

Also I have tried what i have written in inspectLeast() and inspectMost() but Java passes by value not by reference. Any tips?

P.S Not allowed to use anything from java collections or java util.

```
public class PAS43DPQ implements DPQ
{
    //this is the tree
    TreeNode tree = new TreeNode();
    //this is for the size of the array
    int size = 0;

    @Override
    public Comparable inspectLeast() {
        return tree.inspectLeast(tree.root);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable inspectMost() {
        return tree.inspectMost(tree.root);
    }


    @Override
    public void add(Comparable c)
    {
        tree.add(c);
        size++;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable getLeast() {
        if (tree.root != null){

        }
        return getLeast();
    }

    @Override
    public Comparable getMost(){
        Comparable most = getMost();
        return most;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size > 0)?true:false;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return this.size;
    }


    class TreeNode{
        private Comparable value;
        private TreeNode left, right, root;

        //constructors
        public TreeNode() {}

        public TreeNode(TreeNode t) {
            this.value = t.value;
            this.left = t.left;
            this.right = t.right;
            this.root = t.root;
        }

        public TreeNode(Comparable c) {
            this.value = (int) c;
        }

        public void add(Comparable input){
            if(root == null){
                root = new TreeNode(input);
                return;
            } else {
                insert(root, input);
            }
        }

        public Comparable inspectLeast(TreeNode n){
            if (n == null)
                return null;

            if (n.left == null){
                TreeNode least = n;
                return least.value;
            }
            return inspectLeast(n.left);
        }

        public Comparable inspectMost(TreeNode n){
            if (n == null)
                return null;

            if (n.right == null){
                TreeNode most = n;
                return most.value;
            }
            return inspectMost(n.right);
        }

        public Comparable getMost(TreeNode n){
            if(n.right == null)
                return n.value;

            return tree.getMost(right);
        }

        public void insert(TreeNode n, Comparable input){
            if(input.compareTo(n.value) >= 0){
                if (n.right == null) {
                    n.right = new TreeNode(input);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    insert(n.right, input);
            }

            if(input.compareTo(n.value) < 0){
                if(n.left == null) {
                    n.left = new TreeNode(input);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    insert(n.left, input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to modify your TreeNode.getMost(TreeNode n) and TreeNode.getLeast(TreeNode n) similar to the following:

```
public class TreeNode{
    // Also, your parameter here seems to be superfluous.
    public TreeNode getMost(TreeNode n) {
        if (n.right == null) {
            n.root.right = null;
            return n;
        }
        return n.getMost(n);
    }
}
```

Get least should be able to be modified in a similar fashion, but using left rather than right obviously.